# How to check relative date?

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing password recovery code that uses a token and a date stored in `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` format e.g. `2012-09-06 18:59:53`. I use the code below to check if the token key for a user id exists:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `recoveryemails` WHERE `UserID` = '$uid' and `Key` = '$key' and `expDate` >= '$curDate'");
```

I need to add another condition after retrieving the expDate to check whether it's older than 3 days, using PHP. Can anyone help me out with that PHP code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lot easier in MySQL: `WHERE ... AND expdate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 DAY)`

But if you insist on doing it in PHP, you will need:

```
$threedaysago = strtotime("-3 days");
$expdate = strtotime($row['expDate']);
if( $expdate >= $threedaysago) { /* more recent than three days ago */ }
```

Comment: I'd really recommend the pure SQL route. just set `expDate` field to a timestamp type, and have it's default value be `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and delete all expired rows on a garbage cleanup.

Comment: i insist because its some problem with mysql i really cant understand when i try to echo date of today through php it says today is 3rd and and when i try to get date of today by mysql its shows the correct date that is 4th for today. dont know why such difference in time through mysql and php

Comment: review your timezone settings for MySQL and PHP, then restart your servers.

Comment: yes i think i should do that , as i also wanted to use a mysql approach for this

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL

```
expDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 Days)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the MySQL date result in strtotime() and compare to strtotime('- 3 days')